# How to get value by key on any level of json document?

Tags: java, json, dictionary, search, jackson

I write method which parses string. I know that string has a json format.

Also I know that it contains values for `lat` and `lng` but It can be on any level.

I wrote following code to implement getting value by key:

```
Map jsonBodyMap = objectMapper.convertValue(body, Map.class);
String lat = getByKey(jsonBodyMap, "lat");



private String getByKey(Map<?, ?> map, String key) {
    Object value = map.get(key);
    if (value != null) {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }
    for (Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {
        Object entryValue = entry.getValue();
        if (entryValue instanceof Map) {
            String val = getByKey((Map) entryValue, key);
           if (val != null) {
                return val;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

But it doesn't look like a nice solution.

Do you know a better way to implement it?

Comment: You may take look at JSON-P: https://javaee.github.io/jsonp/

Comment: @maio290 any examples?

Answer (score 0):

With slight modification to your method and streams, you can create a two-part recursive function.

```
private static String getByKey(Object obj, String key) {
    if(obj instanceof Map) {
        Map<?,?> map = (Map) obj;

        if(map.containsKey(key))
            return String.valueOf(map.get(key));

        return map.entrySet().stream()
                .map(a -> getByKey(a.getValue(), key))
                .filter(a -> a != null)
                .findAny()
                .orElse(null);

    }
    return null;
}
```

Instead of leveraging the method on a Map, we leverage on an object, convert it to a map if necessary, and then stream the recursive function on it if it's a Map. This reduces the null check to only when the method returns a value, as opposed to whenever we try to get a value from a map.